# Regression Simulation with random variable - Getting pvalue

Tags: regression, p-value, simulation, stata, r-squared

i have the following problem:

I have a sample of individuals who have opinions on certain subjects. I have to group these individuals randomly in groups the same size for every subject and take the mean opinion as a variable in my regression. Some subjects however, have more opinions than others, so i set a the group size to e.g. 5 per subject.
Because i do not see any other way as i can't just ignore the opinions on subjects with more than 5 opinions, i simulate the random group assignment, take their mean opinion, do the regression and save the coefficients, standart errors and R-sqaured. I do that 1000 times.

I know i can just use the mean coefficient as a result but i also want to make a judgement on the statistical significants of the different variables. Am i forced to look at the individual regression and say it was stat. sig. x/1000 or is there a way to get  "summary p-values" for these 1000 regression and their variables? The same question would also be regarding R-squared.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not fully following your logic on selecting 5 and only 5 from each person, your overall strategy for determining the P-value via simulation is heading in the right direction.

However, let me suggest the following adjustment.  Instead of asking if the regression (by which I take this to mean the slope of the regression line) is significant (or the mean or the $R^2$, etc.), use some fixed value for comparison purposes.  Then with your 1,000 simulations, you can ask ¿how many are at or above this value? (or at or below if your result is negative).  This count divided by the number of simulations would be your (bootstrap) simulation P-value.

Happy to clarify more if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The selecting of 5 and only 5 is unfortunately a requirement. How would you determine that fixed value? Would be thankful for more clarification!

Comment: The fixed value would be based on your research question and null hypothesis.  Let's say you want to ask if your model accounts for at least 10% of the variability of the dependent variable...then you would count how many of the simulations had $R^2 > 0.1$.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you will take that into consideration. i'd also would want to display my results in a table. I would take the mean coefficients for my different variables and also take the standart deviation of these coefficients in a table. Does that make sense? Would you display anything else or display it differently. i am not sure as i've only worked with normal regression output so far

Comment: That seems reasonable.  I personally would also include a 5-number summary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insights!